# How can I change the legend in ggplot so it shows both the colour and the linetype for each category?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my dataset, from the `Eurostat` package:

```
structure(list(geo = c("Espanya", "Unió Europea", "França", 
"Zona Euro", "Espanya", "Unió Europea", "França", "Zona Euro", 
"Espanya", "Unió Europea", "França", "Itàlia", "Zona Euro", 
"Espanya", "Unió Europea", "França", "Itàlia", "Zona Euro", 
"Espanya", "Unió Europea", "França"), time = structure(c(19297, 
19297, 19297, 19266, 19266, 19266, 19266, 19236, 19236, 19236, 
19236, 19236, 19205, 19205, 19205, 19205, 19205, 19174, 19174, 
19174, 19174), class = "Date"), values = c(11.8, 5.3, 5.9, 5.8, 
11.7, 5.3, 5.9, 5.8, 11.5, 5.2, 5.8, 7, 5.8, 11.3, 5.3, 5.9, 
7, 5.8, 11.3, 5.3, 6.1)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I did the following graph: [image]

where I indicated the `Zona Euro` line to be dashed. But in the legend I only get a solid line. How can it appear dashed as well?

This is my code:

```
ggplot(taxa_atur, aes(x=time, y=values, color= geo, group=geo, linetype=geo))+
  geom_line(linewidth=0.7, aes(linetype = geo)) +
    scale_colour_brewer(name="", palette = "Set1") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = geo_linetype) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=as.numeric(c(5,15)), breaks=seq(from=5, to=15, by=1)) + 
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), breaks = "2 months", labels=date_format("%b %y"),
               limits = c(as.Date("2020-12-01"), NA)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), color="black")+
  labs(title="Taxa d'atur",
       subtitle= "(% de la població entre 25 i 74 anys)",
       y="",
       x=" ",
       cation="Font: Eurostat. Taxa d'atur corregida d'estacionalitat.")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    text=element_text(family="serif", color="black"),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color="grey90"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color="white"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    plot.title = element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size=10),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.caption.position = "plot",
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "left",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.box.margin = margin(0,0,0,0,"cm"),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size=15),
    axis.line.x=element_line(color="black"),
    axis.line.y=element_line(color="black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=10),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=10),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=10, face="bold",
                                margin = margin(t=12, b= 0, r = 11, l = 5)),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=10, face="bold",
                                margin = margin(t=0, b= 0, r = 11, l = 5)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pre-define a named vector (`geo_linetype` in my example) containing the `linetype` information for each `geo`, and use it to set `scale_linetype_manual(values = geo_linetype)`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

geo_linetype <- setNames(ifelse(unique(taxa_atur$geo) == "Zona Euro", "dashed", "solid"), unique(taxa_atur$geo))

ggplot(taxa_atur, aes(x=time, y=values, color= geo, group=geo))+
  geom_line(linewidth=1, aes(linetype = geo))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = geo_linetype)
```

[image]

Comment: I've just done what you suggested, but it's not working: geo_linetype <- setNames(ifelse(unique(IPI_interanual$geo) == "Zona Euro", "dashed", "solid"), unique(IPI_interanual$geo))

plot1 <- ggplot(IPI_interanual, aes(x=time, y=values, color= geo, group=geo))+
  geom_line(linewidth=0.7, aes(linetype = geo)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = geo_linetype) +
  guides(linetype = "none")

Comment: @Maria Remove `+ guides(linetype = "none")` from your code, it's not in my solution :)

Comment: Okey yes sorry! I have more code and I guess it is overwriting, I'll have a look! :)

Comment: I've just updated my code in the question, if you could please me help clarify what I'm doing wrong... your code workds perfectly but then when I add the rest of mine it doesn't

Comment: @Maria Use `scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = geo_linetype) +`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to go the "hacky" (and more error prone) way and set the linetype via the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend`. For this approach you have to ensure that you change the linetype at the right position, i.e. the fifth in your case and set the right value for the linetype, which in case of just "two" categories is `22` according to `scales::linetype_pal()(2)`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(taxa_atur, aes(x = time, y = values, color = geo, group = geo)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1, aes(linetype = (geo == "Zona Euro"))) +
  guides(
    linetype = "none",
    color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(rep("solid", 4), 22)))
  )
```

[image]